# codeigniter unknown column in 'field list'?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

Controller:

```
            $dbname = 'classified_coupon';
            $data['header'] = $this -> input -> post('header');
            $data['description'] = $this -> input -> post('description');
            $data['type'] = $type;
            $data['category_id'] = $this -> input -> post('main');
            $data['sub_id'] = $this -> input -> post('sub');
            $data['latitude'] = $this -> input -> post('lat');
            $data['longitude'] = $this -> input -> post('lng');
            $data['date'] = date('d.m.Y H:i:s');
            $data['user_id'] = $user_id['username'];
```

Model

```
public function insert($data,$database) {

    $insert = $this -> db -> insert($database, $data);

    if ($insert) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'latitude' in 'field list'

Filename: /home/clipartd/public_html/models/classified_model.php

Line Number: 6

Comment: are you sure the table has **latitude** in it?

Comment: yes  latitude varchar 255

Comment: classified_coupon is your db name? or table name. and the error says you dont have latitude column.check spelling at table column name

Comment: db name classified_coupon . Filed name latitude

Comment: @SerhanYavçin whats the name of your table, try using it

Comment: ok no problem :) Repair my db and my problem was solved